# unable to open MS office files after downloading from gmail

Tags: ms-word, gmail

When I try to open any MS office file `doc, ppt, xls` downloaded from gmail it shows a corrupted message as image shown. How to solve this? Is there a problem in installation?

[image: Error]

Comment: This Q&A site is for programing questions. Your question is better suited to http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried the suggestions shown in the error message?
I'd press the show help button, maybe there's a solution to your problem. Otherwise i don't know what you could do either.